# Reproduce Pivot table with QUERY formula

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a sample [spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdFBsVkxOQ3NENVZ1djhxVmZUNUdtY0E#gid=0) and there is report in Sheet2 using query `=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:D13; "select A, B, C order by A, B, C", 1)` and report in Sheet3 using in build Google spreadsheet pivot table.

How to arrive a same format to pivot table in sheet3 as in Sheet2.

Comment: If you only want to sort the rows by A, then B, then C, I'd say pivot tables are no good for that. They are intended for aggregating values - like calculating totals, averages, etc. You may want to look into SORT function: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093150

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following formula.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:D13; "SELECT A, SUM(C) GROUP BY A PIVOT B")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

This will at least group the names.